# images not showing up in nanogallery2

Tags: nanogallery

I have made a page with following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link    href="css/nanogallery2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<body>
  <div id="nanogallery2" data-nanogallery2 = '{
          "thumbnailHeight":  150,
          "thumbnailWidth":   150,
          "itemsBaseURL":     "file:///home/reginald/dev/nanogallery/"
        }' >
    <a href="video1.mp4" data-ngThumb="thumbnail1.jpg"> Title video 1 </a>
    <a href="video2.mp4" data-ngThumb="thumbnail2.jpg"> Title video 2 </a>   
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When using the code inspector I see that all sources get loaded, but somehow the pictures don't show in the page. What am I doing wrong here?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The script itself is missing. You need to load it also.

Add the following line before the end of the header:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2@2.2.0/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Kris, now the images show up but the video doesn't play in the gallery. Before the images didn't show but the video played well. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This is a different question, it would be good to open a new question with your real source code

Comment: please note that videos must be hosted on Youtube, Vimeo or Dailymotion - https://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/datasource.html#ngy2_comparison

Comment: Thanks for this information. I was looking for a way to play videos from a folder on my filesystem in a lightbox without using a web server. I guess I need some other technology.